# How can I rotate object on key press?

Tags: unity, c#

The script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Scaling change
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;

    private bool scaleUp = false;
    private Coroutine scaleCoroutine;

    //Colors change
    public Color startColor;
    public Color endColor;
    public float colorDuration; // duration in seconds

    //Lights change
    public DimLights dimlights;
    private Coroutine lightCoroutine;

    //Rotate
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float rotationDuration;

    private void Start()
    {
        //startColor = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        endColor = Color.green;
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Update()
    {
        //Scaling
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            //Flip the scale direction when F key is pressed
            scaleUp = !scaleUp;

            //Stop old coroutine
            if (scaleCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

            if (lightCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(lightCoroutine);


            //Scale  up
            if (scaleUp)
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
                lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(1, duration)); ;
            }

            //Scale Down
            else
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
                lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(0, duration)); ;
            }
        }

        //Change color
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());
        }

        //Rotate
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            objectToScale.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            //StartCoroutine(RotateObject());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        //Get the current scale of the object to be scaled
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeColor()
    {
        float t = 0;

        while (t < colorDuration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, t / colorDuration);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RotateObject()
    {
        float startTime = Time.time;

        while (Time.time - startTime < rotationDuration)
        {
            objectToScale.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using StartCoroutine but it didn't work.
So for testing I tried to make that if I'm click/pressing on R once it will rotate the object nonstop but it's not working either it's not rotating it all.

Nothing i click on R and nothing happen.
Tried to change the rotationSpeed from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the code like this:

```
public Update()
{
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
  {
      // If the player is holding the key, rotate the object.
      objectToScale.transform.Rotate( /* How much to rotate */ )
  } else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R)
  {
      // If the user has just let go of the key we want
      // to rotate for N seconds
      StartCoroutine(RotateObject());
  }
}

IEnumerator RotateObject()
{
    float startTime = Time.time

    while (Time.time - startTime < rotationDuration)
    {
        objectToScale.transform.Rotate( /* How much to rotate */ );
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This should rotate the object while the player is holding the key, and after the player releases the key it should rotate for `rotationDuration` more seconds.

It's also important to note that this line `Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * t / rotationDuration` is kind of strange. If you want to rotate the object by `rotationSpeed` every second you should just do `Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You need parts from both of your attempts:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
```

This will trigger exactly once until you let go of the key again. This is exactly the behavior you describe as wanting to have.

```
StartCoroutine(RotateObject());
```

This will do the rotation (via the coroutine function you already have set up).

When you use `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))` and start a coroutine, you end up starting a dozen or more *copies* of the coroutine, all of which are trying to rotate your object and are conflicting with each other, leading to unpredictable behavior.

*Then* you have one other problem:

```
objectToScale.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * t / rotationDuration);
```

This math is almost certainly not doing what you want it to. If you want a *linear* rotation speed, then you want `Time.deltaTime` here. Additionally the `rotationDuration` value isn't needed. Just use this:

```
objectToScale.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Neck to neck with these answers haha :D

Comment: @Charanor Almost! I skimmed yours before finishing mine. I'm not sure that your code does what he wants, but I'm not *actually sure* what it is *he wants.*

Comment: After reading your answer I was also unsure... I got my interpretation from _I want to make that when I press once on R the object will rotate for N seconds ... Then keep rotating it as long as I press on the key._. Perhaps they will tell us in comments if this is what they were trying to achieve.

Comment: @Draco18s What I want is when I click on R once rotate the object at speed 1 for 10 seconds.  I messed up the question.

Comment: @Charanor I messed my question up. What i want is one situation. When i click on R once start the Coroutine. Then for example roate the object on peed 1 for 10 seconds inside the Coroutine. That's it.

Comment: @jdoedoedoedoe Then Draco18s' answer is the correct one. Simply change `Input.GetKey` to `Input.GetKeyDown` and it should work fine.

Comment: @Charanor Tried it not working. I updated my question with my full script code. Tried your solution then tried without StartCoroutine but it's not rotating at all. For testing i tried to make that if i click on R once it will rotate the object non stop but it does nothing.

Comment: @jdoedoedoedoe If the object doesn't rotate when you do `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) { StartCoroutine(RotateObject()); }` then there's probably something else preventing it from rotating, because using this code works just fine for me. By the way, `Transform.Rotate()` takes _degrees_ as its argument, so when you have `rotationSpeed` as 1 it will rotate 1 degree every second (very slowly). Try changing it to 90.

Comment: @Charanor It's working i just found out that the rotationSpeed i set it to 1 so it was moving so slow . If i change it to 1000 it's rotating fast. But isn't it strange that i need to change the speed to 1000 to see it rotating fast ? Not even too fast.

Comment: @jdoedoedoedoe That is because the value passed to the `Rotate()` method is measured in degrees. "360" would get you one full turn every second.